# IBM Watson Assistant input

Tags: ibm-cloud, chatbot, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I'm trying to make my IBM chatbot asking the user question

ex: what's your name?

but there's no choice in define customer response to make it wait for the user answer, it just either options or numbers.

[image: defining skill]

Comment: Are you defining a dialog skill or an action skill? The dialog skill is the chatbot

Comment: I was defining an action skill because 90% of my project is options steps, do I have to do dialog skill? & thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you define a customer response only if there is a special structure (e.g. options) or some special validation ( precentage).

When you model an action there is no need to wait for an arbitrary text from a user, as the intent is already set when the user entered the action.
Therefore in each step it is expected you collect some information from the user.

Comment: ok I get it, but how I make it wait? if I put another step after the name they will run together

Comment: I've updated the answer to address your comment